# Download from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to download a list of email addresses from a database in WordPress to .CSV.

Anybody point me in the right direction:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $data = json_encode($row);
}

outputCSV($data);

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

Comment: What problems did you get with this code? (i can see it's broken, but i'd love to hear your issues first-hand)

Comment: you do realize that "SELECT * FROM table" is just a code example and you need to actually type the name of your table where it says "table", right?

Comment: @travis, yes I do lol

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo '"Header 1","Header 2","Header 3"'."\n";

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_newsletter_signup`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo '"' . $row['column1'] . '","' . $row['column2'] . '","' . $row['column3'] . '"' . "\n";
}

die();
```

Note my content type of `application/vnd.ms-excel` I use this as personal preference due to higher support in older windows machines, but you can continue to use `text/csv` - A list of mime types can be found here http://filext.com/file-extension/CSV

Comment: Seems to return a blank page

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $data = json_encode($row);
}
```

to

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Any way it was a mistake :)